# Count two rows with scopes and relationships (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

So I have two tables, one called `members` and one called `memberships`

My goal is to count the number of members who have a certain membership. I've set up foreign keys and relationships are working fine, to the point where I need to do the counts.

My scope is (in `Member` model)

```
public function scopeActive($query) {
    return $query->where('membership_ended_at', Null);
}
```

My relationship is (in `Member` model)

```
public function membership() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Membership');
}
```

This query works fine, and I see how many members who are `active()` that has the `membership_id` of 6.

```
$members_student = Membership::find(6)->members()->active()->count();
```

I don't know if that's supposed to work, but it does. Now, the issue I have is that we have a regular student membership, and a student abroad membership with the ID of 14.

I assumed maybe this would work, but I quickly realized I was wrong

```
$members_student = Membership::find([6,14])->members()->active()->count();
```

I know I can call two queries and just add the two together, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution. Something that only required one query, and will half my queries.

Hopefully someone else has seen this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to someone on laravel.io chat I managed to figure this one out. Posting it here in case anyone else is also looking for the answer.

The solution:

```
$members_student = Member::whereIn('membership_id', [6,14])->active()->count();
```